# Bar graph(Primary) then Line graphs (Secondary) works fine but do not work if I alter the sequence in the code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to bring that two plots together but when I use Bar graph(Primary) and then Line graphs (Secondary), it works fine. It do not work if I alter the sequence in the lines of codes as regarding the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

flatui1 = ["#0C6514", "#18AB25"]
flatui2 = ["#0E1D56", "#18AB25"]
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui1)
cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui2)
cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
sns.set_style(style='whitegrid')

m1_t = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[0.21,0.05,1.22,0.41,1.28,1.15,0.91,0.63,0.38,1.18],
    "B":[13.33,18,23.69,21.46,35.31,16,20.11,15.87,20.53,17.71],
    "C":[5.71,2,23.44,9.02,35.39,13.48,14.62,13.17,13.68,14.66]
})

# This two line sequence has the problem
m1_t['A'].plot(kind='bar',colormap=cmap1)
m1_t[['B','C']].plot(kind='line',secondary_y=True,colormap=cmap2)


ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.set_xticklabels(('P0', 'P1','P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9'))
plt.savefig('Comparison',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: The below graph shows and I need to collide them without changing the sequce of the graph.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to plot this will be to use the object oriented matplotlib api. First we'll have to define our `Figure` and `axes` then to properly plot a 2nd y, we'll create a pseudo axes object that links back to the original axes we create. Then we can tell pandas to plot on our axes directly to ensure everything goes to the correct place.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

flatui1 = ["#0C6514", "#18AB25"]
flatui2 = ["#0E1D56", "#18AB25"]
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui1)
cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui2)
cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
sns.set_style(style='white') # we don't want the grid coming from seaborn

m1_t = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[0.21,0.05,1.22,0.41,1.28,1.15,0.91,0.63,0.38,1.18],
    "B":[13.33,18,23.69,21.46,35.31,16,20.11,15.87,20.53,17.71],
    "C":[5.71,2,23.44,9.02,35.39,13.48,14.62,13.17,13.68,14.66]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
twin_x = ax.twinx() # Create a pseudo axes based off of the original

# ax is our main plot with the "primary y-axis"
# twin_x is also our main plot, but plotting on this plots
#   our "secondary y" axis

# Put the bar plot on the "primary y" via ax=ax
m1_t['A'].plot(kind='bar',colormap=cmap1, ax=ax, zorder=1)

# Put the line plot on the "secondary y" via ax=twin_x
#  don't have pandas place our legend by default, we'll do this manually for more control later
m1_t[['B','C']].plot(kind='line', colormap=cmap2, ax=twin_x, zorder=2, legend=False)

ax.grid(True, zorder=0)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.set_xticklabels(('P0', 'P1','P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9'))

# to keep the line and bar legends separate:
#  you can simply draw a legend on each one, since each
#  respective Axes holds onto its own data/artists
ax.legend(loc="upper left")
twin_x.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(0, .85))
 
# To create 1 all encompassing legend:
#  you can use fig.legend with some tweaking
#  fig.legend automatically gathers legend information from all Axes on the figure
#  we'll need to give it a bounding box, as well as a new coordinate system so
#  that it will appear inside of the bounds of the Axes (instead of the bounds of the figure)
fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.9, 1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

# Legends on the left are the legends we made with ax.legend(...) + twin_x.legend(...)
# legend on the right is the all encompassing fig.legend(...)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This solution will work regardless of the ordering of the lines of code since we're telling pandas to plot on specific Axes instead of letting it choose to plot on a set of existing Axes or make a new Axes.

---

Edit:

manually specifying zorder is a reliable way to control the order in which elements are drawn. Essentially elements with a higher zorder will be on top of elements with a lower zorder. In this case, our grid has a zorder of 0, and our bar and lines have a zorder of 1 and 2 ensuring they will be placed on top of the grid (since their zorders are higher than 0).

---

Edit 2 (adding legends):

- Legends on the left are the legends we made with ax.legend(...) + twin_x.legend(...)
- legend on the right is the all encompassing fig.legend(...)
  See comments in the code for a description of the approaches

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, how to bring the all the gridlines to the back.

Comment: You'll need to change your seaborn style, then use the `zorder` plot argument on your plotting elements and your grid. I'll update my answer

Comment: That's almost perfect. Thanks. How about putting the legend for the bar one?

Comment: just updated my answer for the two types of legends you may want to make. Not sure if you wanted everything all together in 1 legend, or keep the lines/bars separate

Comment: Thank you very much @Cameron. Very much appreciated for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The following method for two-axis graphs is easy because it keeps the index and includes a legend.

```
# This two line sequence has the problem
# m1_t['A'].plot(kind='bar',colormap=cmap1)
# m1_t[['B','C']].plot(kind='line',secondary_y=True,colormap=cmap2)
ax = m1_t.plot(y='A', kind='bar',colormap=cmap1)
ax1 = m1_t.plot(y=['B','C'], kind='line',secondary_y=True,colormap=cmap2, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How to bring the gridlines to the back. I tried several solutions but none of those works. I wonder if you could have any solutions for that.

Comment: `ax1 = m1_t.plot(grid=False)`This should have been possible, but for some reason I couldn't control it. You can also mitigate the grid lines in a less than optimal way by`ax1.yaxis.grid(color='grey', linestyle='dashed')`